# How to increment page hit count in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Which query is the best for counting page views in Laravel:

```
DB::table('bn_totalhit')->increment('TotalHit');
```

or

```
$totalHit = TotalHitModel::where('ContentID', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();
$totalHit->TotalHit = $totalHit->TotalHit+1;
$totalHit->save();
```

Any suggestions for updating/incrementing page view count for 10000's of page views at a time?

Note: My current server return 503 if traffic is 700+. Server config: 8 core 64 GB.

Comment: DB::table('bn_totalhit')->increment('TotalHit');

Comment: or 
$totalHit=TotalHitModel::where('ContentID','=',$id)->firstOrFail();
 $totalHit->TotalHit=$totalHit->TotalHit+1;
 $totalHit->save();

Comment: Put those in your question, then drop the idea and just put Google Analytics on the site.

Comment: You should put your question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, you will get a better answer regarding performance